# Which forum for workflow and organizing-type questions for the self-employed?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

**Update**

Since the consensus is that none of Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User would be the right place for questions like that and it isn't only about one question, does anybody know a forum that is suited for these types of question (title) and has somewhat near the quality of answers and competence you find at Stack Overflow?

---

**1st version:**

title: On which site should I ask “how self-employed programmers organize their real-life todos”?

Hi,
I have no clue where to ask and I fear that even Meta might be the wrong site, but I got to try somewhere.

I'm pretty impressed with the quality of answers and competence you find at Stack Overflow, and can't think of a better group of people to ask but since this question doesn't have anything to do with programming itself I fear that it doesn't fit on any of SO, Server Fault, or Super User.
(I have a gazillion todo-lists on paper and need to find a better way of organizing it)

A) Can I just ask that on Stack Overflow? (I guess - no)
b) Do you know any site of similar quality that would fit this question?

Comment: Get the book "Getting Things Done" by David Allen, it has the answers.

Comment: Stack Exchange is *not* a forum..

Answer (score 4):

> On which site should I ask “how self-employed programmers organize their real-life todos”?

None of the trilogy.

> I have no clue where to ask and I fear that even Meta might be the wrong site, but I got to try somewhere.

This question is appropriate for Meta, “how self-employed programmers organize their real-life todos”, is not. Here we discuss only about Stack Overflow. And ponies. And waffles.

> I'm pretty impressed with the quality of answers and competence you find at Stack Overflow, and can't think of a better group of people to ask but since this question doesn't have anything to do with programming itself I fear that it doesn't fit on any of SO, Server Fault, or Super User. (I have a gazillion todo-lists on paper and need to find a better way of organizing it)

All of the sites are aimed at *technical* problems. Your question is about workflow, something a bit more subjective than *How to do a loop on Haskell*.

> A) Can I just ask that on Stack Overflow? (I guess - no)

Good guess.

> B) Do you know any site of similar quality that would fit this question?

**I** don't, but maybe somebody here does.

Comment: I like ponies and waffles.

Comment: i like waffles.  ponies, not so much.  (unicorns are right out.)

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you want to ask but [What do you use to keep notes as a developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/what-do-you-use-to-keep-notes-as-a-developer) is very similar and you should find your answer there.

Note that this question was asked a long time ago where off-topic rules were much more relaxed. If it was posted today, it would have been closed right away for being not programming related.

Comment: This was may thought as well. If you *did* ask on SO, I'd vote to close as a duplicate of the above. And I think you will find so general "ToDo list" type questions on SU.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Lifehacker's Five Best To-Do List Managers](http://lifehacker.com/399985/five-best-to+do-list-managers).